# How can I monitor a URL and then email myself a traceroute if something goes wrong?

Tags: perl, curl, wget, ping, traceroute

I found a script online that I thought was going to do what I needed, but I can't get it to work as my PERL skills are pretty low. Basically, I need to monitor this URL on apple.com and make sure the download form is available, and if it isn't available, I need to receive an email saying that the form isn't available from $hostname, here is the traceroute from that host.  The traceroute is important because Apple uses Akamai and some GeoIP magic for their downloads.

I'm open to keeping this script and adding on to it or doing it another way. Thanks for taking the time to look at this for me. I'll be sure to share the finished result when I'm done. I'm pretty sure this script will be useful to more than just myself. ;)

**EDIT** 5/8/2011
I just updated the script to reflect my recent changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

# local hostname
my $hostname = `/bin/hostname`;

# setup array of servers/websites to check
my @sitestocheck = ('swdlp.apple.com');

# the relative url of the website response script in each site
my $responseprogram = "/cgi-bin/WebObjects/SoftwareDownloadApp.woa/wa/getProductData?localang=en_us&grp_code=quicktime&returnURL=http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download";

# path to the log file with the response data
my $statusdir = "./tmp";

# mail feature
my $mailprog ='/usr/sbin/sendmail';
my $adminmail = 'root@localhost';
my $frommail = 'root@$hostname';

###############################################################
# End Configuration                                           #
###############################################################
# main program
use Crypt::SSLeay;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# now check each url in your array
foreach my $sitetocheck (@sitestocheck)
{
    my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
    my $req = new HTTP::Request 'GET',"https://$sitetocheck$responseprogram";
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ($res->is_success) 
    {
        if ($res->content =~ m/Quicktime/i)
        {
             my $response = "SERVER OK:$sitetocheck:".$res->content;}
        else
        {
            my $response = "Our apologies but there was an unexpected error with the application. This problem has been noted, and an email has been sent to the administrators. Please check back in a few hours to try the download again. ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        my $timestamp = localtime;
        my $response = "WARNING! $hostname UNABLE TO CONNECT TO $sitetocheck at $timestamp";
        my $traceroute = `/usr/sbin/traceroute $sitetocheck`;
    }
    # write server status to the main log file
    open(FILE,">>$statusdir/statuslog.txt");
    flock(FILE, 2);
    print FILE "$response\n$traceroute\n\n";
    flock(FILE, 8);

    # write to a current status file for each server or website
    # being monitored
    open(FILE,">$statusdir/$sitetocheck");
    flock(FILE, 2);
    print FILE $response;
    flock(FILE, 8);
}

# if there is an error mail the administrator
if (my $response =~ m/apologies/i)
{
    open( MAIL, "|$mailprog -t" );
    print MAIL "Subject: $hostname unable to connect to $sitetocheck\n";
    print MAIL "From: $frommail\n";
    print MAIL "To: $adminmail\n";
    print MAIL "Reply-to: $frommail\n\n";
    print MAIL "$response\n$traceroute";
    print MAIL "\n\n";
    close MAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's some observations:

1. Always use:

   `use strict;
   use warnings;`
2. Why `chmod 0777`? Does your logfile need to be executable?
3. `$statusfile` does not contain any data.
4. `$traceroute` contains traceroute data, but the data is then replaced with an empty string.
5. If no traceroute is run, you will have a print with an undefined value in the first `open()`, which will cause a warning in perl.
6. Your second `open()` truncates the logfile. Perhaps intentional, but worth mentioning.
7. The checks that are performed are rather loose. First, the only check performed on the page being valid is that it contains `"Quicktime 7.6.9 for Windows XP"`. That could be on any page, even a page saying the system is down. Also, the `$response` is checked for the string "WARNING", which obviously comes from the script itself, but is checked case-insensitively, which is just strange. So, a mail is sent out not only if there is an error, but if the word "warning" appears anywhere on the download page. Not really a very good check, IMO.
8. The `$response` text says an email has been sent to the administrators, which it has not.
9. `"/bin/hostname"` the application is not used, only it's name is added to the Subject of the email. If you want it used, you need to use backticks like with traceroute (I would show you, but apparently backticks are a metacharacter in this textfield ;))

The webpage seems to come through ok, I can't test the sendmail since I am on a windows machine, but it looks ok.

It is hard to tell if this fixes your problems, since you do not specify what your problems are. It is a rather crude script, though.

Comment: You're right, the script emails me regardless of if the page is ok or not okay. ;) Also, the only thing that currently shows up in the logfile is the source of the page I'm checking. 1) Added. However, this gives a ton of "Global symbol requires explicit package name"  errors. ;) 2) Removed. This was from the original script. 3) I don't see $statusfile in the script. 4) I think this is now fixed. 5) Ok. 6) Not sure that matters at the moment. 7) See above. 8) Email does work on my linux machines. I get an email whether or not the site is ok or not ok. ;) 9) Fixed.

Comment: 1) With `use strict` you have to declare variables, e.g. `my $statusdir;` Make sure to put the declaration within the scope you intend to use it, which most likely will be simply at the top of the file. 2 & 3) Since it's not used, it is most likely safe to remove. 4 & 5) If you declare like this at the top you will remove the error: `my $traceroute = "";` Replace the mailing check with `if ( $response =~ /^WARNING/)` And find something unique on the apple page, that will not appear on an error. Or something that you know will appear on the error page.

Comment: Connecting to http:// works, but connecting to https:// does not. Otherwise, I think I've got the script working like it should.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the above code to reflect all the changes and how far the script has come. I'm still having some issues getting the last few "Global symbol" errors fixed though. Global symbol "$response" line 51; Global symbol "$traceroute" line 51; Global symbol "$response" line 58; Global symbol "$sitetocheck" line 66; Global symbol "$traceroute" line 70.

Comment: When you use `my` to declare a variable, it is only declared inside the current block. E.g. `{ my var = 1; } print $var # not ok` . If you intend them to be global variables, define them at the top of the script. Also, you can't declare them multiple times. Once is enough. This: `my $response =~ m/apologies/i` is a direct error, because you are performing a search on a variable during declaration, which means it is empty.

Comment: I'm never going to get this to work. That's what I get for trying to tackle PERL and not really having experience with PERL. ;)